# How to extract rasters with the same extent from a list of rasters in R

Tags: r, raster, gdal, extent

I have a list object made up of rasters and there are two types of rasters in it in terms of their extent. How can I extract the ones with the same extent and save them as a new list in R? It is not possible to give a reproducible example but the code below can help you understand the question.

A hypothetical example:

```
library(raster)
list_raster # Suppose this is a list having 48 rasters.
names(list_raster) <- paste0("raster", seq(1:48)) # Assigning names makes it possible to use the dollar sign.
lapply(list_raster, extent) # Gives 48 results but only two unique raster extents.
#  I would like to know which of the rasters has == extent(list_rasters$raster1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply`:

```
same_as_r1 <- sapply(list_raster, function(x) extent(x) == extent(list_raster$raster1))
```

And subset your list with it:

```
group1 <- list_raster[same_as_r1]
group2 <- list_raster[!same_as_r1]
```